# Swipe to delete working on multiple cells at the same time in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am supporting swipe to delete feature in my UITableView. I am seeing that in iOS 7, I can swipe on multiple rows and delete button appears up on all the rows. Its working fine in iOS 6. Is there a way to restrict this to one cell only the way it works in iOS 6?

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    int aNoOfRows = self.productCount;

    if (iIndexPath.row < aNoOfRows)
        return YES;

    return NO;
}


- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    UITableViewCellEditingStyle anEditingStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

    int aNoOfRows = self.productCount;

    if (iIndexPath.row < aNoOfRows) {
        anEditingStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    return anEditingStyle;
}
```

Comment: we need your code because .. I cant do that out of the box :)

Comment: I have my code that allows delete option for my cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with iOS 7. Have reported it and it should probably be fixed in next iOS release. Not sure why I got down votes here.

Answer (score -1):

See this example, this way you don't need to change the tableView on editing mode and you can swipe delete on the `indexPath.row > 5`, also you can get the delete button being pressed in the commit int `-tableView commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark tableView delegate methods

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Test" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %i", indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // The condition for your cells to become editable
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // do whatever you need to do on the delete event for each indexPath
    // this is where you remove the cell and before that you need to manipulate
    // your array so when the delete is called, it gets the proper count, etc.
}

@end
```

Comment: But I want all my rows deletable. Its just that I do not want user to delete multiple rows at the same time.

Comment: Then in the `canEditRowAtIndexPath:` return `YES` always. I edited my answer as well.

Comment: Thats not the issue. Issue here is that using my 2 fingers I can swipe on two different cells and I can see Delete buttons on both the cells which I do not want. Like in iOS 6, I want Delete button to be exclusive per cell.

Comment: that's weird cause i tried and could't get two delete buttons to show up... only one shows up always.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with iOS7 SDK.

Answer (score -1):

Set as below to disable editing multiple cells at the same time.

> tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;